# anchor tag with twitter bootstrap not working for ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucguy/kse4gg1r/) for my scenario after trying [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/Hp4W7/34/). Somehow the **contractNum** is not populating here but in my project it's populating.I have searched a lot and implemented all solutions what I got but can't make the anchor-link workable so that it can call a method in controller with a parameter.
**If no parameter is passed in ng-click with anchor then it works fine** but something is bugging it with parameter is passed. Please help me to resolve it.

View:

```
 <div ng-app="home" >

<div ng-controller="homeCtrl" ng-repeat="item in items">
                        Contract number<a href="" ng-click="getAssetDetail(item.jumboId)">  {{item.contractNum}} </a> <br />                 

</div>
<div>
```

and Controller:

angular.module('home', []).controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

```
 var items=[{contractNum:"123", serialNum:"ABC1" },
         {contractNum:"121", serialNum:"ABC2" },
         {contractNum:"124", serialNum:"ABC3" },
         {contractNum:"125", serialNum:"ABC4" } 
        ];


 $scope.getAssetDetail = function (jumboId) {

        alert('you got'+jumboId);

    };
 }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off your items need to be a property on the $scope, not just a local var.

Secondly, there is no property called jumboId on your items, so that is why you get undefined.

Maybe you are trying to get the serialNum in your alert? If so take a look at this.

Fix your items:

```
$scope.items=[{contractNum:"123", serialNum:"ABC1" },
             {contractNum:"121", serialNum:"ABC2" },
             {contractNum:"124", serialNum:"ABC3" },
             {contractNum:"125", serialNum:"ABC4" } 
            ];
```

and fix your html:

```
Contract number<a href="" ng-click="getAssetDetail(item.serialNum)">  {{item.contractNum}} </a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gLrz0u4k/

Comment: That is working in Jsfiddle but why can't I get the same behavior in my Application? When I pass an argument with ng-click , it stops working!

Comment: what if you just pass the entire item? Then set a breakpoint in the debugger to see what properties your item has.